# Save uipickerview color in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uipickerview

I know what I want, but I'm just struggling to get it the right way. I'm trying to implement a small app, which let the user  add a category by providing a category name, description and then select colour from the uipickerview. I've successfully saved the name, description in the core data. I'm just struggling in how to get the selected colour string and save it in the core data. Any help will be appreciated. This is what I've so far as code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class NewCategory: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let categoryColor = ["Red","Yellow","Black","White", "Green", "Blue"]

    // MARK: - Properties
    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    // MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionField: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var colorLabel: UILabel!


    // MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func saveBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

        if name.text == "" || name.text.isEmpty || name.text.isEmpty{
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "WARNING !!!", message: "Couldn't add category. Fill all fields.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            createCategory()        }

    }

    // MARK: View settings
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.pickerView.dataSource = self
        self.pickerView.delegate = self
    }

    // Custom functions
    func createCategory() {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: context!)
        let category = Category(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

            category.name = name.text
            category.descript = descriptionField.text
            category.color = colorLabel
            println(category.name)
            context?.save(nil)
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return categoryColor.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return categoryColor[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if (row == 0) {
            colorLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
        else if(row == 1) {
            colorLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        }
        else if(row == 2) {
            colorLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
        else if(row == 3) {
            colorLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
        else if(row == 4) {
            colorLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        }
        else {
            colorLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the color name this way:

```
let index = pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
let color = categoryColor[index]
```

For example, you could use it in your function like this:

```
func createCategory() {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: context!)
        let category = Category(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

            category.name = name.text
            category.descript = descriptionField.text

            let index = pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
            let color = categoryColor[index]
            category.color = color // (assuming color is a String)
            println(category.name)
            context?.save(nil)
    }
```

Comment: What i'm asking is how to pass  the selected index to the createCategory()

Comment: how will it fit in this func createCategory() {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: context!)
        let category = Category(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

            category.name = name.text
            category.descript = descriptionField.text
            category.color = colorLabel
            println(category.name)
            context?.save(nil)
    }

Comment: ok but why is it not getting applied on my label when I fetch it from the core data? override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("categoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell
        let category = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Category
        cell.colorPicked.backgroundColor =  category.color as? UIColor
        println(cell.colorPicked.description)
        return cell
    }

Comment: This code would work, the problem is elsewhere, maybe in the other tableviews data structure or your data model

Comment: I think the problem is in your `category.color as? UIColor`. If category.color is a string, you can't convert it to UIColor the way you do it. You need to do something similar as you do in your pickerView didSelectRow.

Answer (score 0):

In `didSelectRow` get the value from `categoryColor`

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       let colorString = categoryColor[row] as! String

        // Save the colorString into Core data

    }
```

Comment: how to pass it in this function ?  func createCategory() {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: context!)
        let category = Category(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
        
            category.name = name.text
            category.descript = descriptionField.text
            category.color = colorLabel
            println(category.name)
            context?.save(nil)
    }

Comment: you can create colorString as global variable or you can pass this string into the method as  func createCategory(colorStr:String)

Comment: sorry but I'm very new in swift and mobile development. This function func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       let colorString = categoryColor[row] as! String

        // Save the colorString into Core data

    } is the default coming from apple. I don't think I can access it, if I create a func as you suggested createCategory(colorStr:String), how will it be used in 
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
      pickedColor = categoryColor[row]. sorry for the question

Comment: or do you mind illustrating that in the code I've posted